# Frequent disconnects over LAN?

Tags: civilization-5, technical-issues

I'm experiencing frequent disconnects while playing Civilization V in multiplayer over my home wired LAN. I do not experience something like that in other multiplayer games. Is there any known solution or workaround to this problem?

The disconnects always happen shortly after a new turn have started, and it seems to get worse as the game progresses; at the moment, turn ~300, it disconnects almost every turn, making the game unplayable. Of note is that every time we reconnect, the game enables us to play the turn but it rollbacks the AI's last turn, in effect giving us a free turn.

I've found some recent complaints about this on [the Steam forums](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=2842050) and on [the 2K forums](http://forums.2kgames.com/showthread.php?143196-CIV-V-Multiplayer-Disconnects-after-each-turn), but could not find any solution.

Comment: How much traffic is currently communicating on your LAN?

Comment: @Foxtrot none, other than the game and background communications. We even closed stuff such as Dropbox and Google Drive just to be sure.

Comment: hmm... And you have disabled A/V and Firewalls?  Does this happen to you when you play a game over WAN as well?

Comment: @Foxtrot haven't disabled various security measures... but I have a feeling the game is more at fault than the network, seeing as how it happens more frequently as the game advances more.

Comment: I have the same problem. The later versions of the game seem to be better - Gods and Kings seems to suffer less. Another thing that seemed to help was starting the game on the best spec'ed PC and joining the others to that. Finally only playing on Tiny or Small maps helps. I still have the problem on occasion though so this is not an answer.

Comment: What happens if you play your LAN games over the internet?

Comment: Wireless on wired LAN?

Answer (score 1):

Civ5's netcode is a horrible mess (actually, all Civ5 code is).
We noticed (while playing over internet) that slow player computers can affect the loading times in later games and disconnects happen more frequently. I don't think there's anything you can do about it. Set autosave to 5 rounds and hope for the best. ;)

Answer (score -1):

These problems used to plague multiplayer and were patched.  Make sure your LAN/Internet settings from a router/modem are fine.

If all else fails I would highly suggest purchasing the expansions to play the game with Gods and Kings or Brave New World.  There is lots of balancing that occurs that Firaxis did not patch into non-expansion Civ 5.  I hate to support laziness on behalf of the developers/publishers but the fixes are worth it if you intend to play.

Now for the bad news, sadly all Civ5 games seem to deteriorate over time.  The game simply cannot handle itself and late games always turn to lagfests riddled with disconnects, bugs, and glitches.  My advice: SAVE, SAVE, SAVE.  Save every few turns to save yourself nightmares and every 30-50 turns I suggest creating a new save file to keep an archive of the game.  I have experienced save files becoming corrupted and unusable for in-explainable reasons.   One certain reason was after a patch.  Patches frequently corrupt save files.

Despite all of that, the game is still amazing which is why I play it.  My normal configuration is 2 player MP on huge maps with exactly 7, 8, or 9 AI. (Whatever the # is w/out the WARNING).

Turning off settings like Unit movements and automoving cameras have increased our game's stability as well as made the game faster.

Hope this helps somewhat. Best of luck in your conquests.